# Django:datefield showing constant time

Tags: python, django, date, models

This is my model:

```
class messages(models.Model):
    status_choices = (
        (u'read',u'read'),
        (u'unread',u'unread')
        )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=6,choices=status_choices,default='unread')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="sender")
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today,editable=False)
```

So now every message has "date" field set to "12:00 AM - 11 Jul 2012".Why is that so?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're doing datetime.date.today and not datetime.date.today() ?

Comment: Actually,I read somewhere(on some other post on stackoverflow) that it's "datetime.date.today",but I have no idea which one is correct :)

Comment: I meant yes, what you have above is better.  For anyone else that stumbles upon this, you don't want to call the function because then you'll set all your defaults to the time you started up Django.  And that will cause bugs that really really confuse people : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime.date.today()` does not return time values, so it's defaulting to midnight. Change your last line to `date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, editable=False)`.

Comment: "default=datetime.datetime.now()" worked for me.Btw I think that "TIME_ZONE = US/Eastern" setting in settings.py is also responsible for difference in the time.I'm in India so the time is different here.